# Adjust spacing between linebreaks

Tags: spacing, amsmath, koma-script

I would like to adjust the spacing between two lines within a *gather* environment. My MWE is this:

```
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.

\begin{gather}
    \text{LBG} [\%] = \frac{\text{AP}_\text{L}}{\text{AP}_\text{G}} \cdot 100\\
    \begin{aligned}
        \\
        &\text{LBG} &&= &&\text{Lieferbereitschaftsgrad} \\
        &\text{AP}_\text{L} &&= &&\text{S\"amtliche Auftragspositionen, die im Betrachtungszeitraum} \\
        &&&&& \text{fristgem\"a\ss{} vom Lager bedient worden sind} \\
        &\text{AP}_\text{G} &&= &&\text{S\"amtliche Auftragspositionen, die im Betrachtungszeitraum} \\
        &&&&& \text{in das Lager eingegangen sind}
    \end{aligned}
    \notag
\end{gather}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.

\end{document}
```

This results into the following. The spacing which I try to eliminate is marked in yellow:
[image: Example]

Answer (score 3):

Instead of (mis-)using a combination of `gather` and `aligned` you could use a normal `tabular` with a `p{}`-type column for the descriptions. This could be wrapped up in a custom environment, `eqdescription` or something.

The example below uses the `center` and the `tabular` environments but it uses the internal commands in the definition of `eqdescription`, i.e., `\center` and `\endcenter`, and `\tabular` and `\endtabular`. In the column specification `l@{${}={}$}p{.7\linewidth}}` we have a `l`-type column and a `p`-type column with a width of `.7\linewdith`. Between the columns `@{${}={}$}` inserts a `=`.

```
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\newenvironment{eqdescription}
  {\center\tabular{l@{${}={}$}p{.7\linewidth}}}
  {\endtabular\endcenter\addvspace{\baselineskip}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.

\begin{equation}
  \text{LBG}[\%] = \frac{\text{AP}_\text{L}}{\text{AP}_\text{G}} \cdot 100
\end{equation}
\begin{eqdescription}
  LBG & Lieferbereitschaftsgrad \\
  $\text{AP}_\text{L}$ &
    S\"amtliche Auftragspositionen, die im Betrachtungszeitraum
    fristgem\"a\ss{} vom Lager bedient worden sind \\
  $\text{AP}_\text{G}$ &
    S\"amtliche Auftragspositionen, die im Betrachtungszeitraum in das Lager
    eingegangen sind
\end{eqdescription}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I've added a negative space, but this isn't a good solution, IMHO :-(

```
\begin{gather}
    \text{LBG} [\%] = \frac{\text{AP}_\text{L}}{\text{AP}_\text{G}} \cdot 100\\
    \begin{aligned}
        \\
        &\text{LBG} &&= &&\text{Lieferbereitschaftsgrad} \\
        &\text{AP}_\text{L} &&= &&\text{S\"amtliche Auftragspositionen, die im Betrachtungszeitraum} \\[-1ex]
        &&&&& \text{fristgem\"a\ss{} vom Lager bedient worden sind} \\
        &\text{AP}_\text{G} &&= &&\text{S\"amtliche Auftragspositionen, die im Betrachtungszeitraum} \\[-1ex]
        &&&&& \text{in das Lager eingegangen sind}
    \end{aligned}
    \notag
\end{gather}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can halve the line spacing and add an extra empty line when needed.

```
\usepackage{setspace}

%[...]

\begin{spacing}{0.5}
\begin{gather}
    \text{LBG} [\%] = \frac{\text{AP}_\text{L}}{\text{AP}_\text{G}} \cdot 100\\
    \begin{aligned}
        \\
        &\text{LBG} &&= &&\text{Lieferbereitschaftsgrad} \\~\\
        &\text{AP}_\text{L} &&= &&\text{S\"amtliche Auftragspositionen, die im Betrachtungszeitraum} \\
        &&&&& \text{fristgem\"a\ss{} vom Lager bedient worden sind} \\~\\
        &\text{AP}_\text{G} &&= &&\text{S\"amtliche Auftragspositionen, die im Betrachtungszeitraum} \\
        &&&&& \text{in das Lager eingegangen sind}\\~\\
    \end{aligned}
    \notag
\end{gather}
\end{spacing}
```

Alternatively, use a parbox for your multi-line descriptions.

```
        &\text{AP}_\text{G} &&= &&\text{\parbox[t]{0.7\textwidth}{S\"amtliche Auftragspositionen, die im Betrachtungszeitraum in das Lager eingegangen sind}}\\
```